# Take multiple separate inputs from lines read in from file in C

Tags: c, function

Basically I have a few problems.

The problem I am trying to solve involves a "banking program" that gets its info from a text file. It reads the first five lines of code (which are all floats) and uses each as the starting balance.

Next, the following 1-5 lines of code each begin with a single character indicating the account that it affects. Next is a single letter indicating either withdraw or deposit, etc. Following that is the amount that will be used in the action. I have to use multiple functions.

Here's what I have so far, I know some spaces have been left in pseudocode while I'm working on it.

```
  float balance();
float withdraw();
float deposit();
float update();

#define INTEREST 3.5;
int main(){

//initializing variables
int count =0,count2=0,acctNum=1,acct1,acct2,acct3,acct4,acct5,i=0;
float orgBalance, balance;
char activity,B,W,U,D;

//opening files
FILE *input;
input = fopen("bankfile.txt","r");

//error checking that file opened correctly
if (input == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
    exit(1);
}   
printf("Account          Balance\n");
printf("------------------------\n");
while(count<5){
    fscanf(input,"%f",&orgBalance);

    //printf("%d               %.2f\n",acctNum,orgBalance);
    //acctNum++;
    i++;
    count++;
    printf("%d balance is %.2f\n",i,orgBalance);
}
printf("------------------------\n");


while(fscanf(input, "%d ",&i)!=EOF){
//while(count2<5)
    fgetc(i);   


    switch (activity){
        case 'B':
            balance;
            ;
            break;
        case 'W':
            withdraw;
            ;
            break;
        case 'D':
            deposit;
            ;
            break;
        case'U':
            update;
            ;
            break;


    }
    count2++;
}


system("pause");
return 0;
}


 float balance(){
    float bal;
    return bal; 
  }
  float withdraw(){
    float bal1, bal2;
    if(bal1>bal2){
        return bal1 - bal2;
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry, you can't withdraw that much");
        return bal1; 


}
}
float deposit(){
    float bal1,bal2;
    return bal1 += bal2;
}
float update(){
    float bal;
    return bal*= INTEREST;

}
```

Comment: how did (not) it work?

Comment: Looks like a good start. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @BinaryJudy, I guess I'm not exactly sure how to take the different types of inputs and then perform the actions following that.

Comment: @Stephen Rosedale Are you still struggling? It's not clear to me what the text file looks like can you provide an example? You have five balances followed by five 'transactions'?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't had much luck in trying to find a solution, or even an idea how to implement it. An example would be 
"100 
400 
500 
600 
800
2 W 200
4 D 500
33 W 150
0"

I'm sorry I can't get it to post all in single lines.

@BinaryJudy

Comment: @Stephen So "2 W 200" would withdraw 200 from 400 (the "2" means account #2 in the list)? Also, can you use arrays?

Comment: @BinaryJudy yes! That's exactly it. I'm just trying to figure out how to first take the "2" then use the Withdraw function. I'm also unsure of how to save the original balances to separate floats.

Comment: @BinaryJudy, I have some knowledge in arrays from a C++ class but am unsure of how to implement them in C.

Comment: @Stephen Okay, I guess what are I mean is are you allowed to use them? If this is an assignment is your instructor going to question why you used an array?

Comment: Yes, we're allowed to use them; I don't believe there would be any problem!! @BinaryJudy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the accounts like this using an array:

```
float ogAcnts[5] = {0,0,0,0,0}; // original account balances initialized to zero
fscanf(input, "%f%f%f%f%f", &ogAcnts[0], &ogAcnts[1], &ogAcnts[2], &ogAcnts[3], &ogAcnts[4]);
```

You can have a second array with the new balances if you need to keep the original balances for future reference:

```
float newAcnts[5] = {0,0,0,0,0}; // initialized to zero, could also be replaced with the original balances
```

To display the original account balances:

```
// you can fill in the rest
for(int i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
    printf("%d balance is %.2f\n",i,ogAcnts[i]);
}
```

You can skip the account balances in the file when scanning, like this:

```
fscanf(input+5, %d%c%f, &acountNum, &transactionType, &amount); // note these variables don't exist in your code but it's an example of how you could use them
```

You can then follow this same method to get the remaining transactions. Get the transaction parameters and act on them. Use the arrays to access the balances instead of the file. The first account will be element 0 and ends with account number 5 being in index 4 (zero based). So you will have to follow this pattern. I say that because of how the transactions are labeled with the account number (either starts with 0 or 1). if you are using zero based then it makes it easier to access that account balance in the array. Like this example "2 W 200" if account #2 has 400 in it and you are starting with the first account being account 0, you can pass the account number and amount to your transaction functions like this:

```
...
newAcnts[accountNum] = ogAcnts[accountNum]-amount; // withdraw example using the variables from above
```

Note: It would probably be better to just have one running balance for each account unless (like mentioned) you need to know what it was before you started. Because for any additional transactions on the same account you'd want to use newAcnts[accountNum] to have the correct balance of the account. Or before starting any transactions copy the original balances into the new accounts array and only do your transactions on the newAcnts array. Hopefully that makes sense :)

```
newAcnts[accountNum] = newAcnts[accountNum]-amount; // withdraw example
```

Comment: Hope that helps you out some.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I am implementing those changes right now! Will let you know how it goes in a bit!

Comment: I added those first two arrays and when I compile and run all I get is "5 balance is 0.00"

Comment: @Stephen Okay, let me know if you have trouble. I didn't test any of that but it should be right or really close to being right ;)

Comment: @Stephen Take a look at this [link](http://rextester.com/ADJI38809). It runs part of it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having problems now passing the actual numbers from the array to each of the functions... @BinaryJudy

Comment: @Stephen I wasn't around over the weekend. I hope you got everything figured out. I'll try to help you out more if you still need it.

Answer (score 1):

these are wrong

```
switch (activity){
    case 'B':
        balance;
        ;
```

....

you mean

```
switch (activity){
    case 'B':
        balance(); <<<======
        ;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the pseudocode I had left in there. I'm not sure how to grab the info in order to get to that point yet.